# UITextField does not show the assigned string

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In my project (my first one) I try to assign a text to a textfield created in the Interface Builder.

```
[date setText:@"2010"];
```

I also tried using

```
date.text = @"2010"
```

I have created the Outlet and don't get any error... the text just doesn't show up.

Just in case it matters...
I prevent the keyboard from showing up and display a calendar instead (works).

Any idea what could be wrong?
Could it be a problem that I'm using delegate methods on the textFields to prevent displaying the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to edit text using a keyboard, then what is the use of UITextField?
Instead of using UITextField you can use a UILabel (as a global variable) to show the text and use a custom UIButton without a title and use its action for showing the calendar view. You can change the text of the label whenever you want in that class like viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: I think I might try that as my current implementation does not work.

Comment: I finally went this way... now I will be looking into styling the button to look like TextFields.